# Advantages of tomcat jar scan

Tags: tomcat, jar, tomcat9

Recently i am trying to upgrade tomcat to version 9. on then i figure out there is jar scan feature in tomcat.

I go through [Tomcat Jar Scan](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) could not find reason why they have introduce this feature.

So what i want to know is

- what type of errors can be avoided via jar scanner ?
- What type of jars we should ignore / we should scan ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is reference also in Tomcat7 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this feature to control where tomcat looks for configuration files like TLDs.  It can be used to resolve some INFO logs that may occur during tomcat startup.  Resolving issues like this can improve tomcat startup time:

> "INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging  for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in  them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time."

See http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/how-to-get-your-tomcat-to-pounce-on-startup-not-crawl